# Custom diagnostic rule not being applied in C# using Roslyn API

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have implemented a custom diagnostic rule in C# using the Roslyn API, but it is not being applied to my code. I have verified that the rule is included in the list of enabled rules in my project's code analysis settings and that code analysis is enabled for the project. However, when I build the project, no compilation errors are reported for code that should trigger my custom rule.

Here is the code for my custom rule:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class MoreThanOneNamespaceInFileIsNotAllowedAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "MyRules0001";

    private static readonly LocalizableString Title = "This is a title";
    private static readonly LocalizableString MessageFormat = "This is a message";
    private static readonly LocalizableString Description = "This is a description";
    private const string Category = "Naming";
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId,
    Title,
    MessageFormat,
    Category,
    DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
    true,
    Description);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
        context.RegisterSyntaxTreeAction(AnalyzeAction);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeAction(SyntaxTreeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var syntaxRoot = context.Tree.GetRoot(context.CancellationToken);

        var descentNodes = syntaxRoot.
            DescendantNodes(node => node != null && !node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration));

        var foundNode = false;
        foreach (var node in descentNodes)
        {
            if (node.IsKind(SyntaxKind.NamespaceDeclaration))
            {
                if (foundNode)
                {
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, Location.None));
                }
                else
                {
                    foundNode = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code that I expect to trigger a compilation error:
Because two namespaces are defined in a single file.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {


    }
}

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class2
    {

    }
}
```

And here is the .editorconfig

```
# My custom StyleCop rule
dotnet_diagnostic.MyRules0001.severity = error
```

I have also pushed a sample project to [GitHub](https://github.com/m-khooryani/RoslynDemo) that reproduces the issue. Can anyone help me understand why my custom rule is not being applied and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `OutputItemType` with value set to `Analyzer`. For example:

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyCustomRules\MyCustomRules.csproj">
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
  <OutputItemType>Analyzer</OutputItemType>
</ProjectReference>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I applied your suggested change and now I can see the custom rules project in Analyzers but with a red (ignored) icon. What does it mean?

Comment: @M.Khooryani I can't repro the issue - try rebuilding the project (if does not help try building with `dotnet build`, restarting VS, deleting bin/obj folders)

Comment: @M.Khooryani just FYI your code from repo with my update produces the `"This is a message"` error during the build for me.

Comment: Strange! which IDE you are using? might be relevant?

Comment: I'm using Rider on Ubuntu. But again, try using `dotnet build` from command line.

Comment: Yes, it works with dotnet build. but not in VS. Is it the same with Rider also?

Comment: @M.Khooryani no, it works just fine in Rider. I don't have VS setup at hand but when something is not working in IDE I tend to consider `dotnet build` as "source of truth" ( just FYI by working I mean if I invoke build command from the IDE I get build error).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why you received one -1 but Thank you from my side +1 :)